# SQL can't insert linebreak with CHAR(13): no function with name 'char' exists

Tags: sql, plsql

Please help me, it's disturbing, I'm trying to insert a simple line break. (Windows)

My PL/SQL code is:

```
DECLARE  str varchar2(32767);
BEGIN  str := 'A Text' + char(13) + char(10) + 'Next text';
INSERT INTO atable (...) (str);
END;
```

I always get the error:

> PLS-00222 no function with Name 'CHAR' exists in this scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is [**`CHR`**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/function.htm#TTSQL217)

e.g. -

```
select chr (65) from dual;
```

---

```
A
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But now I get the error: 'ORA-06512: PL/SQL: error converting char to number'  Do you have an idea?

Comment: @StringForever The concatenate operator in Oracle is || (and not +)

Comment: @StringForever P.s. since this was a correct answer please mark it as such. Thanks

Comment: @StringForever, my pleasure. It seems you are used to SQL Server, so you'll have to work close to the Oracle documentation